# Sort files alphabetically before processing

Tags: find

I use the command

```
find . -type f -exec sha256sum {} \; > sha256SumOutput
```

to hash every file in a folder hierarchy. Unfortunately, `sha256sum` doesn't get the file names from `find` in alphabetical oder. How can this be fixed?

I'd like to have them ordered **before** they are hashed so they are hashed in alphabetical order (this has a reason).

Comment: Find files, pipe to `sort` to  sort the list,  and pipe to sha256sum

Comment: Alphanumeric sort.

Comment: Already answered at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34325/sorting-the-output-of-find .

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Using some pipes and `sort`

```
find . -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -r0 sha256sum > sha256SumOutput
```

---

*Explanation*

From `man find`

```
   -print0
        True; print the full file name on the standard output, followed
        by a null character (instead of the newline character that -print
        uses). This allows file names that contain newlines or other
        types of white space to be  correctly  interpreted by programs
        that process the find output.  This option corresponds to the -0
        option of xargs.
```

From `man sort`

```
   -z, --zero-terminated
        line delimiter is NUL, not newline
```

From `man xargs`

```
   -r
        If the standard input does not contain any nonblanks, do not run
        the command. Normally, the command is run once even if there is
        no input. This option is a GNU extension.

   -0   
        Input items are terminated by a null character instead of by
        whitespace, and the quotes and backslash are not special (every
        character is taken literally).  Disables the end of file string,
        which is treated like any  other  argument. Useful when input
        items might contain white space, quote marks, or backslashes.
        The GNU find -print0 option produces input suitable for this mode.
```

---

*Example*

```
% ls -laog
total 4288
drwxrwxr-x  2 4329472 Aug 17 08:20 .
drwx------ 57   20480 Aug 17 08:20 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1       0 Aug 17 08:16 a
-rw-rw-r--  1       0 Aug 17 08:16 a b
-rw-rw-r--  1       0 Aug 17 08:16 b
-rw-rw-r--  1       0 Aug 17 08:16 c

% find . -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -r0 sha256sum                  
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855  ./a
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855  ./a b
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855  ./b
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855  ./c
```

The values in the first column are the same, as the files don't have any content in my test.

Comment: this works with sha256sum, but not with echo... why?

Comment: @Michael If your command ends with `... | xargs -r0 echo` what exactly do you mean "not working"? By design, `echo` will echo multiple parameters on a single line. If you want each file on a separate line, you can use `... | xargs -r0 printf "%s\n"` instead.  However, note that **filenames can include line breaks**, too.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to just pipe your output from `find` to `sort`.

Comment: Yeah, but then there is no `-exec` switch.

Comment: I don't believe `find` has any way to alphabetize the output, but piping to `sort` and then using `xargs` would give the expected output. `find . -type f | sort | xargs sha256sum`. Although it would have issues with subdirectories..

Comment: Hacky way to deal with sub directories would be `find . -type f | awk -F/ '{print $NF, $0}' | sort | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sha256sum`

Comment: This prints the error `xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
sha256sum: invalid option -- 'l'
Try 'sha256sum --help' for more information.`.

Comment: My guess is one of your files has a single quote in the name

Comment: If that is the case this should work: `sha256sum $(find . -type f | awk -F/ '{print $NF, $0}' | sort | awk '{print $2}')`

Comment: It prints `No such file or directory` errors when there are spaces in file names. Also, I have some files beginning with a date like `2015-08-17 someFileName` and it seems to have special problems with that.

Comment: This method is too hacky to be honest, there are tons of legal file names and it will fail on most of the strange ones. I can add a way to deal with the spaces, but then maybe something else comes up. I am sure there is a way to use `find` and `xargs` but I am kind drawing a blank right now.

Comment: "Unfortunately, sha256sum doesn't get the file names from find in alphabetical oder. How can this be fixed?" "Pipe `find` to `sort`" is an answer to that question, hold your fire.

Comment: See answer https://askubuntu.com/a/662383/50254 instead to see how to correctly handle all special characters in filenames.