# Comparing directory sub-structure and file names ignoring file type/extension

Tags: command-line, directory, file-format

This has been partly covered by [Comparing the contents of two directories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421712/comparing-the-contents-of-two-directories) but I have a slightly twist on this problem.

I have directories Dir1 and Dir2. Their subdirectory structures should be the same, which is something I want to check. But I also want to check the files within them. They should have the same file names but every file within Dir1 has extension .type1 and every file in Dir2 has .type2. When I use the solution linked above Dir1/bob/file.type1 and Dir2/bob/file.type2 are viewed as different.

How do I make the above linked solution blind to extensions?

Comment: What should the output look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
diff <(cd Dir1 && find . | sort | sed 's/\.type1$//') <(cd Dir2 && find . | sort | sed 's/\.type2$//')
```

could be a solution.

The command will hide `.type1` and `.type2` extensions in both directories so they won't impact the `diff`.

Here's a simple example:

```
user@hostname:/tmp/test-diff$ find Dir* | sort
Dir1
Dir1/file1.type1
Dir1/file3.type1
Dir2
Dir2/file2.type2
Dir2/file3.type2
Dir2/file4.type2
```

The `diff` command will highlight that `file1` is in `Dir1` (`<`), but not in `Dir2` and `file2` and `file4` are in `Dir2` (`>`), but not in `Dir1`

```
user@hostname:/tmp/test-diff$ diff <(cd Dir1 && find . | sort | sed 's/\.type1$//') <(cd Dir2 && find . | sort | sed 's/\.type2$//')
2c2
< ./file1
---
> ./file2
3a4
> ./file4
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to go towards an answer. (cd Dir1 && find . | sort | sed 's/\.type1$//') and (cd Dir2 && find . | sort | sed 's/\.type2$//') each return a "bleached" directory and file listing but the diff outputs directories they both have and some lines like "7c9,16" and "2a3,4" . If I had to guess it's not allowing "missing files" to be skipped over, ie if Dir2 is missing file 3 of 10 then the last 7 files will not line up with the file names from Dir1.

Comment: @AlphaNumeric I think I don't fully get the problem. I added an example in the answer. If you want only the file names (with the "directory indicator") you can just `| grep '^[<>]'`

Comment: Hi Max. The expanded edit you made cleared things up a lot and I understand what the output was giving now. I'll "accept" your answer now. Thanks for your help.